# Save visitor's ip and timestamp with at least 1 minute interval in Laravel

Tags: laravel

My application will save users' IPs and timestamps once they visit a specific page.

```
if (! auth()->check()) {
        $attributes = [
            'type' => 'Visited',
            'description' => 'The proposal was recently visited by someone with IP address '.\request()->getClientIp(),
            'ip' => \request()->getClientIp()
        ];

        (new ProposalLogController())->store($proposal, $attributes);
    }
```

Here's how I store all the details with IPs:

```
public function store($proposal, $attributes)
{
    $proposalLog = new ProposalLog();
    $proposalLog->proposal_id       = $proposal->id;
    $proposalLog->event_type        = $attributes['type'];
    $proposalLog->event_description = $attributes['description'];
    $proposalLog->ip_address        = $attributes['ip'];
    $proposalLog->user_name         = $attributes['user']??'';
    $proposalLog->save();
}
```

When a user reloaded or refreshed the page, it happened to save the same IP and timestamp again. What is the best way to prevent committing the same IP address & timestamp at the same time, or any laravel specific function that handles this issue?
Example:

First save: `127.0.0.1` `2023-01-16 19:22:33`

Second save: `127.0.0.1` `2023-01-16 19:22:33`

What I want is it should only save when timestamp is at `2023-01-16 19:23:33` it matters in 1 minute interval and it doesnt matter the seconds only the minute so that it wont save multiple entries when the user refresh the page too fast.

Note that it's fine to save the same IP address but with time interval of at least 1 minute to prevent from saving multiple same ip and time.

I already created a fix for this with the below code:

```
if (! auth()->check()) {

        $log = ProposalLog::where('ip_address', \request()->getClientIp())->where('proposal_id', $proposal->id) ->latest()->first();
        if ($log) {
            $logTime = date('Y-m-d g:i', strtotime($log->created_at));
            $now     = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d g:i');

            if ($logTime !== $now) {
                $attributes = [
                    'type' => 'Visited',
                    'description' => 'The proposal was recently visited by someone with IP address '.\request()->getClientIp(),
                    'ip' => \request()->getClientIp()
                ];
                (new ProposalLogController())->store($proposal, $attributes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show how you are storing the ips for the users, how is ProposalLogController linked to the users.

Comment: Make the entry unique on some condition and use catch try around the `->store` line.

Comment: @KGG I've made changes to post added store function.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, you can utilize the request validator and the rule of unique to accomplish this by doing the following:

**Add this to the top of the controller:**

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

**Modify your store function:** make sure to change the `your_table_here` with your table name.

```
public function store($proposal, $attributes)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($attributes, [
        'ip_address' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('your_table_here')->where(function ($query) use($attributes) {
                return $query->where(['ip_address' => $attributes['ip_address'], 
                                      'user_name' => $attributes['user_name']]);
            }),
        ], 
    ]);
        
    if ($validator->fails()){
        //You can return whatever view, or just simply ignore this, you can use it for now for testing.
        return 'ip address exists for the user.';
    }else {
        $proposalLog = new ProposalLog();
        $proposalLog->proposal_id       = $proposal->id;
        $proposalLog->event_type        = $attributes['type'];
        $proposalLog->event_description = $attributes['description'];
        $proposalLog->ip_address        = $attributes['ip'];
        $proposalLog->user_name         = $attributes['user']??'';
        $proposalLog->save();
    } 
}
```

**The above will basically do the following query on validation:**

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS aggregate
FROM
  `your_table_name`
WHERE
  `ip_address` = 127.0.0.1
  AND (
    (
      `ip_address` = 127.0.0.1
      AND `user_name` = abcd
    )
  )
```

Comment: Please check my updated code above. @KGG

Comment: @VicAndam your solution doesn't make sense, it will still duplicate the IP address on record while my solution checks if the IP exists for the user, it wont add it since there is a record for it. Of course that can be improved a lot.. but that was your original requested solution. Now its really unclear what kind of solution you are looking for.

Comment: I also edited my description sorry for that @KGG